# Generic histogram sp: setting my range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm creating a generic stored procedure to return histogram data.

My input parameters are:

```
@tableName nvarchar(100),
@columnName nvarchar(100),
@rangeMin real = null,
@rangeMax real = null
```

If my ranges aren't provided, then rangeMin and rangeMax are simply the MIN() and MAX() of @columnName.

The problem I'm having is that I don't know the proper way to set @rangeMin and @rangeMax when my tableName is dynamic.

A direct query to SET @rangeMin/@rangeMax doesn't seem to work because my tableName is a string parameter.

On the other hand, I could change the stored procedure's signature to provide a table variable rather than a table name, but my table is big (usually on the order of a few gigs) and it's not clear if passing in a large table valued parameter is a good idea or not.

*edit*: My attempt looks like this

```
    DECLARE @SQLQuery nvarchar(max) = '
        SELECT @x = MIN(@columnName)
        FROM '+@tableName+';
    '
    DECLARE @parmDef nvarchar(MAX) = N'
    @x nvarchar(50) OUTPUT, @columnName nvarchar(100)';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery, @parmDef, @x=@rangeMin OUTPUT, @columnName=@columnName;
```

*edit2: The above doesn't work (it sets @x to the value of @columnName for some reason...)
But the following does work:

```
 DECLARE @SQLQuery nvarchar(max) = '
        SELECT @x = MIN('+@columnName+')
        FROM '+@tableName+';
    '
    DECLARE @parmDef nvarchar(MAX) = N'
    @x nvarchar(50) OUTPUT';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery, @parmDef, @x=@rangeMin OUTPUT;
```

I'm still unclear on whether it would have been preferable to just pass in the table to my sp.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterizing your dynamic sql here is only a portion of the issue and really isn't needed here because you can't parameterize the table name and that is part of the requirements. I have to say that creating a generic procedure like this is a bit strange but whatever. Also, there really is no need for an output parameter from your dynamic sql. Just have the dynamic sql return that value.

Something like this should work.

```
create procedure DynamicMin
(
    @columnName sysname
    , @tableName sysname
) as
begin
    set nocount on;

    DECLARE @SQLQuery nvarchar(max) = '
        SELECT MIN(' + QuoteName(@columnName) + ') as MinValue ' +
        'FROM ' + QuoteName(@tableName);

    PRINT @SQLQuery;

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery;
end
```

Comment: Just curious, why is it a bit strange to create a generic histogram procedure?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by histogram procedure. It seems like a generic query to get a minimum value from any table and column is not something that would be very useful but I don't know your system.

Comment: Ah my bad, I'm only showing a small part of the procedure.  I need the min and max because I'm binning my data.

I find the range, distribute the rows into the appropriate bucket, etc.